# Option for Coloring the Background of pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have been looking for a simple answer for this with no success. I want to plot the function y=x^2, and color the background of the whole box made up by the `axis` environment. Intuitively, one would think that a `fill` option would be available for `axis`, but it turns out it is not! Are there no simple solutions to this? Also, what if I want to expand the coloring outside the `axis` box.

Of course, one can manually add a rectangle and adjust it's dimensions as needed, but this is not convenient.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzplot}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[fill = grey!10,] % This option does not work, why????
         \addplot {x^2};
      \end{axis}

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From page 95 in the pgfplots documentation. Use the `axis background/.style` for the `axis` environment!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{axis}[axis background/.style={fill=gray!10}]
         \addplot {x^2};
      \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Any thoughts on the syntax structure in pgfplots. It's quite confusing.

Comment: It takes some time to get used to, I guess. Keep asking questions! :-)